# op amp adjustable ramp generator

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: op amp adjustable ramp generator]

I traced this circuit from Induction Motor soft starter.  My questions are:

1. What is the function of Q5 & Q6?
2. How the integrator opamp pin 5,6,7 works, which transistor is used to reset the cap?

It appears to me that custom design was implemented here compare to basic op amp ramp generator like in the question [Ramp Generator using op amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202943/ramp-generator-using-op-amp).

Comment: You could add labels to the opamps to identify them without spelling all the pins. Or you could refer to them as "Niger opamp" "Tchad opamp" and "Zimbabwe opamp" ;)

Comment: As to the function of Q5 and Q6, it's better to ask the author of the schematic. I don't even understand what components they are. Maybe lego pieces.

Comment: As I mentioned "I traced this circuit from Induction Motor soft starter." meaning  no Author.  Q5 and Q6 is a universal standard electronics symbol for transisitor.  Since no label on my rough sketch I used pin number to identify which opamp Im referring to.

Comment: btw the ref voltage is -7V from U1C pin 3.

Comment: The whole circuit is a Motor Soft Starter. It will ramp only on power up then reset after preset time by H RAMP POT then stay reset till next power OFF ON cycle.

Answer (score 1):

1) Q5 & Q6 create a [current mirror](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror?wprov=sfla1)
2) U1b (pins 5,6,&7 as well as U1a) is used as a [comparator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: Glad that Grifplex had recognized my rough sketched diagram. As per your label U1a is comparator but U1b is monostable. Q5 & Q6 look like current mirror due to layout but one of this is to latch the relay and the other one is to reset the timing capacitor connected to pin 6 and mid of POT H RAMP. My problem is I cant figure out which is which?

Comment: I see the feedback on U1b now, it was a little late last night. It is really strange to see the base shorted to the emitter like that on Q5.

Comment: That is my confusion too. Any idea from this site will be highly appreciated.